# Is it possible to adjust a jpeg subsamping with php?

Tags: php, jpeg, subsampling

I'm making an image uploader for a client and working on minimizing file size.  Already adjusting quality, setting optimize and progressive, removing exif data, just looking for a way to adjust subsampling and smoothing.
Just wondering if there is a php function which can adjust a jpeg's chroma subsampling to 4X2X2 rather than 4X4X4.  I don't use IMagick, so I'm wondering if there is some regular php function to do it.

Comment: Have you checked the php's `gd` functions?

Comment: yes, but it's not apparent that any of them do such a thing.

Comment: Well, you have answered your question :-) `gd` mostly provides trivial manipulations.

Comment: Is GD the only set of functions that PHP uses to work on images? Apart from plugins like IMagick?